# containedIn query for Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Coming from Parse, I have heavily relied on the `containedIn` query to collect the right data. In Parse, I might have had an array of `objectIds` and queried for all objects with those ids. I am looking to achieve the same on Firebase.

I understand that it is important to flatten data, but I don't see how this helps with the problem. Let's say I have a chat room with a list of users inside it. I collect that data and now have an array of usernames. I would like to now navigate to the users in the database and retrieve all that match one element inside this username array. How can I accomplish something like this?

For example, a set of users in a official Firebase example:

```
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": { ... },
    "ghopper": { ... },
    "eclarke": { ... }
  }
}
```

I would like to perform a query to download the following users:

```
["alovelace", "eclarke"]
```

While a general answer would be helpful, an answer in Swift would be best. Thank you.

Comment: From your comment, I think you understand my question, but I did an example to make it more clear.

Comment: What is the correlation between the users lovelace and eclarke? i.e. what makes those two user nodes important? Loading the nodes is pretty simple but getting to why you want to is critical to how your Firebase is structured.

Comment: An example is that they are the two members of a chat room. Or that the current user is following them.

Answer (score 1):

> An example is that they are the two members of a chat room. Or that
>   the current user is following them.

So a theoretical users node

```
users
   alovelace
      followed_by
        bill: true
        frank: true
      in_chat_room: room_42
      location: France 
   ghopper
      followed_by
        jay: true
      in_chat_room: room_27
      location: USA
   eclarke
      followed_by
        frank: true
      in_chat_room: room_42
      location: Canada
```

and some chat rooms

```
chat_rooms
   room_27
    ghopper: true
   room_42
    lovelace: true
    eclarke: true
```

To get the detailed users nodes of users in chat room 42 (lovelace, eclarke)

```
let usersRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("users")

usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("in_chat_room").queryEqualToValue("room_42")
     .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
     for child in snapshot.children {
       let location = child.value["location"] as! String
       print(location) //prints France and Canada
     }
})
```

To get the users Frank is following (lovelace, eclarke):

```
let usersRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("users")

usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("followed_by/frank").queryEqualToValue(true)
     .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
     for child in snapshot.children {
       let userName = child.key as String
       print(userName)
     }
})
```

Note that using user names as node key's is generally a bad idea - they should be stored by their uid.

Also note we didn't really do anything with the chat_rooms node but to maintain the relationship, having nodes refer to each other can be useful for observing changes etc.

Edit:

In response to a comment, here's the structure for each user to show who they are following instead of who is following the user

```
users
   alovelace
      following_user
        bill: true
        frank: true
      in_chat_room: room_42
      location: France
```

with this structure, alovelace is following bill and frank.

To get all of the users following frank:

```
let usersRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("users")

usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("following_user/frank").queryEqualToValue(true)
     .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
     for child in snapshot.children {
       let userName = child.key as String
       print(userName)
     }
})
```

Comment: This seems a little messy to me. Why should a user store all other users who are following them? Wouldn't it be cleaner, (and easier) for each user to store who they are following? Instead of `user -> [followedBy]` shouldn't it be `user -> [following]`? How would you restructure the data to accommodate this?

Comment: There are many ways to structure the data - you had asked 'and the current user is following them' so I structured it to show who a users followers were. You could flip that around and show who a user is following - or both! See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. But I still don't understand how it would be possible to download all the profiles of the users contained in the following_user. Instead of collecting all users that are following Frank, I would like to collect all users contained in following_user. So for example, create a query that would return both bill and frank.

Comment: I was thinking that there may not be any way to do this. Instead, the followed_by method of organizing should be used, especially because Firebase tries to be real time. It sounds logical to store which other users I'm following, but in Firebase it makes more sense just to store which users are following me.

Comment: @Acoop The code I posted above does what you are asking *how it would be possible to download all the profiles of the users contained in the following_user.*  It downloads all of the users nodes that are following frank or (the other code snippet) downloads all of the user nodes that frank is following. It answers the question but it seems you have another follow up question? Perhaps you should post another question as that answer may be different.